# Which should I use in MATLAB: max(A(:)) or max(max(A))?

Tags: performance, matlab, max

I get a pretty consistent time difference for small matrices in favor of `max(A(:))`:

```
>> A=rand(100); tic; max(A(:)); toc; tic; max(max(A)); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.000060 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000083 seconds.
```

but for large matrices, the time difference is inconsistent:

```
>> A=rand(1e3); tic; max(A(:)); toc; tic; max(max(A)); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.001072 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.001103 seconds.
>> A=rand(1e3); tic; max(A(:)); toc; tic; max(max(A)); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.000847 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000792 seconds.
```

same for larger,

```
>> A = rand(1e4); tic; max(A(:)); toc; tic; max(max(A)); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.049073 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.050206 seconds.
>> A = rand(1e4); tic; max(A(:)); toc; tic; max(max(A)); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.072577 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.060357 seconds.
```

Why is there a difference and what would be the best practice?

Comment: `tic`-`toc` is not very accurate for that. You should use `timeit`. Interesting question anyway

Comment: Don't do timing in the command prompt.  There is significant overhead.  You should instead place your timing in a function script.  You should also set a random seed before invoking `rand` because the actual content of the matrix will also factor into your timing.  This will also promote reproducibility.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Using `timeit` on the same problem the OP proposed (`n = 1000`). I got on average about `0.01s` at each invocation for both methods.  There's about a `0.001s` difference between them both.  Sometimes one was faster than the other by this much.  It doesn't look like there's much of a difference in timing.

Comment: @Sparkler - I wouldn't say that the timing is "inconsistent".  For `n=1000` the resolution of the timing is still within the same precision.  A difference of `5e-4s` is hardly a sign of inconsistency.

Comment: @rayryeng Maybe post the timings as an answer? It would be interesting to see. However, I'm afraid the comparison may be very influenced by the physical characteristics of the machine (cache and stuff)

Comment: @LuisMendo I agree with the bias! However I'm not sure if I should post the timings. It doesn't really help answer the question as I can't explain why the timing would be the same between both styles of `max`

Comment: Short answer: figure it out for *your machine* and *your version* of Matlab using `timeit` or another careful method. Unless you really need those extra tenths and hundredths of milliseconds, I think `max(A(:))` is clearer, works for any dimension `A`, and may well get faster in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [horchler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933375/which-should-i-use-in-matlab-maxa-or-maxmaxa#comment44265617_27933375) says this is machine dependent. However, on my machine I saw a clear performance decrease for the `max(max(max(...` for higher dimensions. I also saw a slight (but consistent) advantage in speed for `max(A(:))` for a more sorted type o matrix as the `toeplitz` matrix. Still, for the test case that you tried I saw hardly any difference.

Also `max(max(max(...` is error prone due to all the paranthesis I would prefer the `max(A(:))`. The execution time for this function seems to be stable for all dimensions, which means that it is easy to know how much time this function takes to execute.

Thirdly: The function `max` seems to be very fast and this mean that the performance should be a minor issue here. This means that `max(A(:))` would be preferred in this case for its readability.

So as a conclusion, I would prefer `max(A(:))`, but if you think that `max(max(A))` is clearer you could probably use this.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine there are no differences in times that are really worth worrying about.

```
n = 2:0.2:4;
for i = 1:numel(n)
    a = rand(floor(10^n(i)));
    t1(i) = timeit(@()max(a(:)));
    t2(i) = timeit(@()max(max(a)));
end

>> t1
t1 =
  Columns 1 through 7
   7.4706e-06   1.5349e-05   3.1569e-05    2.803e-05   5.6141e-05   0.00041006    0.0011328
  Columns 8 through 11
    0.0027755     0.006876       0.0171     0.042889
>> t2
t2 =
  Columns 1 through 7
   1.1959e-05   2.2539e-05   2.3641e-05   4.1313e-05   7.6301e-05   0.00040654    0.0011396
  Columns 8 through 11
    0.0027885    0.0068966      0.01718     0.042997
```